# value too small or too big error

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

str1 and str2 are string variables, that keep a value of the node to be accessed, in this case str1 = "abc" and str2 = "efg". Variable x is an integer, when I run my program I get a "value was either too large or too small for int32" error:

```
XPathDocument xmlDoc = new XPathDocument(path);
XPathNavigator course= xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();                 
XPathNodeIterator value = course.Select("/root/x[@atr =" + str1 + "]/y[@atr =" + str2 + "]/value1");
x = Convert.ToInt32(value.Current.Value);
```

my xml is:

```
            <root>
                <x atr = "abc">
                    <y atr ="efg">  
                        <value1>12</value1>
                        <value2>25</value2>
                        <value3>16</value3>
                    </y>
                </x>
            </root>
```

Comment: What if you print that value, instead of feeding it to Convert.ToInt32? (your XPath and xml don't match in this post)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I need to load the value at Xpath to a variable

Comment: @Thymine has explained the problem which is that the value of your XPathNodeIterator is represented as the concatenation of all nodes in the xpath expression. If you have many nodes the value will likely be too large to be converted to an Int32. To get the value of a single child node use the MoveNext() method and convert the value to Int32....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit:** Its a simple case of this: `"/root/x[@atr ='" + str1 + "']/y[@atr ='" + str2 + "']/value1"` you need quotes around the string of the attributes in the path.

Yours would build the xpath `/root/x[@atr=abc]/y[@atr=efg]/value1` this builds `/root/x[@atr='abc']/y[@atr='efg']/value1`  As with most languages, strings need quotes around them in an xpath too.

---

The problem with your original code is that with `XPathNodeIterator` you need to call `value.MoveNext();` before calling `value.Current`

```
XPathNodeIterator value = course.Select("/root/x/y/value1");
value.MoveNext();
x = Convert.ToInt32(value.Current.Value);
```

---

Full sample code I'm using:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<root>
    <x>
        <y> 
            <value1>12</value1>
            <value2>25</value2>
            <value3>16</value3>
        </y>
    </x>
</root>");

////Also works for XmlDocument
//XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
//doc.LoadXml(@"<root>
//  <x>
//      <y> 
//          <value1>12</value1>
//          <value2>25</value2>
//          <value3>16</value3>
//      </y>
//  </x>
//</root>");

XPathNavigator course = doc.CreateNavigator();

XPathNodeIterator value = course.Select("/root/x/y/value1");
Console.WriteLine(value.Current.Value);  //Outputs 122516, which is the same as doc.Root.Value or XmlDocument.InnerText
value.MoveNext();
Console.WriteLine(value.Current.Value);  //Outputs 12, correctly
int x = Convert.ToInt32(value.Current.Value);  //Parses fine
```

Comment: Are you certain the exception is coming from this code? Could we see where you load the xml and create the Navigator? I created my own sample code that works great with your xml sample.

Comment: I've updated my code to include where the load file statement and create navigator statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use XDocument's extension method [XPathSelectElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083.aspx) like in the below example:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<root>
    <x atr = 'abc'>
        <y atr = 'efg'> 
            <value1>12</value1>
            <value2>25</value2>
            <value3>16</value3>
        </y>
    </x>
</root>");

var x = int.Parse(doc.XPathSelectElement("/root/x[@atr =\"abc\"]/y[@atr = \"efg\"]/value1").Value);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: Using this, I get a "data at the root level is invalid" error?

Comment: var doc = XDocument.Parse(file.xml). Do I need to parse the actual content?

Comment: @JeliBeanMachine: When I run the code I get no error and the expected result is printed.

Comment: @JeliBeanMachine What happens if you just copy and paste my answer? XDocument.Parse parses a string. You need to use [XDocument.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx) for a file.